# How many users can be monitored in debug log?

Tags: debug

As there is no way to get a report or statistics on how many webservice calls made by the users per day and also to find how much response time they are getting while running each visualforce page or a webservice call, i chosen the hardest way by just setup the users in the Monitored users in debug log. In that way i can atleast get some idea on how many milliseconds a webservice call responded as well as the page performance. Now,

1. How many users can be monitored in debug log?
2. Is there any governor limit or limitations in doing the above?

Comment: Why don't you build a custom logging mechanism? A custom object and just create records each time the web service has made a callout or it's being called. That way you can also trace back any issues as well as times

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get the total callout statistics per day for all the users in a salesforce org?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44053/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-total-callout-statistics-per-day-for-all-the-users-in)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a user limit but more users will bring you to the other limits faster:

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_debugging_debug_log.htm
The following are the limits for debug logs:

- Once a user is added, that user can record up to 20 debug logs. After a user reaches this limit, debug logs stop being recorded for that user. Click Reset on the Monitoring Debug logs page to reset the number of logs for that user back to 20. Any existing logs are not overwritten.
- Each debug log can only be 2 MB. Debug logs that are larger than 2 MB are reduced in size by removing older log lines, such as log lines for earlier System.debug statements. The log lines can be removed from any location, not just the start of the debug log.
- Each organization can retain up to 50 MB of debug logs. Once your organization has reached 50 MB of debug logs, the oldest debug logs start being overwritten.